# Change icon on Hovering a dropdown menu in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css

Firstly first, I'm using '**antd**' React framework and tailwindCSS just for practice in ReactJS. Well, this is my first time using this framework. So, I decided to first try with dropdown fly-out menus on hovering.

Actually, not having too much idea how to achieve this stage. I know surely using CSS, I can use "hover: " attr, but is there any idea to use logic in ReactJS? Also, I tried to read the props "API Section of the dropdown menu" but was unsuccessful. Even though I try to use `onMouseEnter()` as a prop in `<Dropdown>`, still couldn't get this.

I have shared this codesandbox to show the current status.

Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-icon-on-hovering-drop-down-menus-bte71b?file=/src/App.js)

I want to change the icon of the dropdown menu on hovering using `<UpOutlined />` and `<DownOutlined />` this is what I imported from "@antd/icons" in ReactJS and I'm using tailwind CSS.

As expected I want like this: a [demo of hovering menus of a dummy website](https://icecreamapps.com/v/hvv3u9a)

Any help would be appreciated, I'm struggling to achieve this since yesterday :(

Comment: Could you create a working example on [codesandbox](codesandbox.io/s/react-new) and update your question?

Comment: Hi @RubenSmn, Thank you for your response! Yes sure, I'll update this question with a working code sandbox example..

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with the working codesandbox example, please have a look on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `onOpenChange` function on the `Dropdown` to get the open state, see [the dropdown props](https://ant.design/components/dropdown?theme=dark#dropdown). Which you can use to set some state of your own. And finally use that state to show a different icon.

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

return (
  <Dropdown
    // ...
    onOpenChange={setIsOpen}
  >
    <span>
      <Space>Hover me, Click menu item</Space>
      {isOpen ? <UpOutlined /> : <DownOutlined />}
    </span>
  </Dropdown>
);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!!, Actually I have also same logic to use "useState" but didn't know how to implement the logic :( I think you saw when you have gone to earlier codepen link. But, Again thank youu